# Wordpress - Changing Background-Color of Multiple Divs

Tags: css, wordpress, background-color, jsfiddle

I have multiple DIV elements on my page with the class "grid-item-container"

I want to make the background-color of each one different. I will set an array of 5 different colours that can be set.

There is a script available here that seems to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/VXG36/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var randomColors = ["green","yellow","red","blue","orange","pink","cyan"];
$(".random").each(function(index) {
    var len = randomColors.length;
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
    $(this).css("backgroundColor",randomColors[randomNum]);
    //Removes color from array so it can't be used again
    randomColors.splice(randomNum, 1);
});
});
```

I cannot however get it to run on my page. Is there something in this script that needs to be amended to make it Wordpress friendly?

Kind regards
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wan't to wrap it in something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
   // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict() mode (see wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js). This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link. Read more about it in Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Also, change $(.random) to $(.grid-item-container), this targets the class of your div.

Comment: So I've added this to my header file:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var randomColors = ["green","yellow","red","blue","orange","pink","cyan"];
$(".random").each(function(index) {
    var len = randomColors.length;
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
    $(this).css("backgroundColor",randomColors[randomNum]);
    //Removes color from array so it can't be used again
    randomColors.splice(randomNum, 1);
});
});
</script>